# kill old thread in node.js and start working with new one

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, multithreading, sockets

I am in very difficult situation due to node.js's thread concept. and it's hard to explain you. but i will try to explain you as possible as simply way.

i am making a web service / RESTful Api for android. and for that i am use some simple code as well as webSocket too.

on android there is two button

1. On click "Open Socket" Button.
   it will open a web socket.
2. On click "close Socket" button
   it will close the web socket.

now from node.js side i need to send response for example 1 to 100 numbers in response.

so, i am use recursion method that will respond on every 30 seconds

Now, i will press the button

```
THREAD A : [1];             i will get 1
-----------------------------
THREAD A : [1,2];           i will get 1,2
-----------------------------
THREAD A : [1,2,3];         i will get 1,2,3
```

Now i will close the web socket by pressing "Close Socket" button then

```
THREAD B : [4]              i will get 4
THREAD A : [1,2,3,5]
-----------------------------
THREAD B : [4,6]            i will get 4,6     (But i want 4,5,6)
THREAD A : [1,2,3,5,7]
-----------------------------
THREAD B : [4,6,8]          i will get 4,6,8   (But i want 4,5,6,7,8)
THREAD A : [1,2,3,5,7]
```

Now i will close the web socket by pressing "Close Socket" button then

```
THREAD C : [9]               i will get 9
THREAD B : [4,6,8,11]          
THREAD A : [1,2,3,5,7,10]
-----------------------------
THREAD C : [9,12]            i will get 9,12 (but i want 9,10,11,12)
THREAD B : [4,6,8,14]          
THREAD A : [1,2,3,5,7,10,13]
-----------------------------
THREAD C : [9,12,15]         i will get 9,12,15 (but i want 9 to 15 all)
THREAD B : [4,6,8,14,17]          
THREAD A : [1,2,3,5,7,10,13,16]
```

So, how can i delete all old thread in Node.js.

Comment: Tried to synchronized your service and then check socket connection

Comment: my service is already synchronised.

Comment: i think this is the same concept like event loop